# Square wave function in FFT spectrum

Tags: frequency-spectrum

The input function is a 60Hz square wave.[image] From Fourier Transform I know that the frequency on the spectrum is 60,180,300....(2k-1). But there's a series of 120,240,360...(2k) signals appear.   [image]
I've googled but all I found is Fourier Transform issues, not Fast Fourier Transform. I'm wondering why there are some 2k terms appearing on the spectrum.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like aliasing.

Your 360 Hz is probably not a real component at 360 Hz but it's the 9th harmonic (540 Hz) that aliases back to 360 Hz at a 900Hz sample rate.

That's easy to test: change the sample rate to, 940 Hz and see of the 360Hz moves to 400Hz or stays put. It moves to 400Hz, it's clearly aliasing.

Comment: Why does aliasing happen? I know if it violent the Nyquist Theorem it will appear. But the sampling rate is 10 times the input frequency.

Comment: A square wave contains an infinite amount of harmonics. The Nyquist criteria applies not just to the fundamental frequencies but to any frequency in the signal which is infinite for a square wave. All harmonics that are below the Nyquist frequency will be sampled correctly. All harmonics above the Nyquist frequency will alias.